# not sure why i can't get addMouseListener(this()), addMouseMotionListener(this()) to work

Tags: java, this, jpanel

So this is the panel for my RocketShip and I want to add my MouseListener and my MouseMotionListener to it but it is telling me that "this" is an invalid name. My textbook uses this sometimes and the professor also recommended that we use "this" in this instance so I am stuck about what the problem is. My code is below for example. Thanks for any advice you might offer.

```
    import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;           
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

//I cannot understand how to draw my new rocketship or how to update the coordinates for mouse moved, mouse dragged, mouse pressed or mouse released
//also not sure how to work with setShooting
public class RocketShipPanel extends JPanel implements MouseListener,MouseMotionListener
{
    private final int WIDTH = 300, HEIGHT = 300;
    RocketShip ship = new RocketShip();

    public RocketShipPanel(){ //constructor
        addMouseListener (this());
        addMouseMotionListener (this());

        setBackground (Color.black);
        setPreferredSize (new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
    }


    public void paintComponent (Graphics page)
    {
        super.paintComponent(page);

        ship.draw(page, 50);


    }

    public void mousePressed (MouseEvent event)
    {
        ship.setShooting(true);
        repaint();
    }
    public void mouseReleased (MouseEvent event) 
    {
        ship.setShooting(false);
        repaint();
    }
    public void mouseMoved (MouseEvent event)
    {

        Point point1 = event.getPoint();
        int x = point1.x;
        int y = point1.y;
        ship.move(x, y);

        repaint();
    }
    public void mouseDragged (MouseEvent event)
    {

        Point point1 = event.getPoint();
        int x = point1.x;
        int y = point1.y;
        ship.move(x, y);

        //pointList.add(event.getPoint());

        repaint();
    }
    //--------------------------------------------------------------
    //  Provide empty definitions for unused event methods.
    //--------------------------------------------------------------

    public void mouseEntered (MouseEvent event) {}
    public void mouseExited (MouseEvent event) {}
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event) {}


    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame ("RocketShip");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.getContentPane().add (new RocketShipPanel());

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need the parentheses after `this`. It's like a variable name, not a method.

Comment: Thank you, I feel like a fool now

Comment: @Josh - Don't. We all make obvious mistakes at some point in our programming careers. Those are often the hardest to find...

Answer (score 0):

this is a keyword in JAVA and it should not be treated as a method, it is a reference to the current object. You can learn about this keyword in the following link - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html